# custom list style not working with wordwrap

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

How can I fix the problem? point 3 should be like the others but out of the wordwrap it makes problems.. also the wordwrap should have the same margin like the other lines. What is going wrong?

[image]

this is the code behind:

```css
.gruene-liste {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: gruene-liste-number;
}

.gruene-liste li { position: relative; margin-bottom: 20px;}

.gruene-liste li::before, .gruene-liste li::after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -0.4em;
}

.gruene-liste li::before {
  content: counter(gruene-liste-number, decimal);
  counter-increment: gruene-liste-number;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.gruene-liste li::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<ol class="gruene-liste">
 <li>Das Ultrakurzzeitgedächtnis speichert Infos bis zu 10 Sekunden lang</li>
 <li>Das Kurzzeitgedächtnis speichert Infos bis zu 20 Minuten lang</li>
 <li>Das Langzeitgedächtnis, dessen Speicherdauer von der Stärke der Verankerung der Nervenzellen durch Synapsen abhängt.</li>
</ol>
```

Another problem see answer at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just position the graphic absolute and add some pagging to tase :D

```css
.gruene-liste {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: gruene-liste-number;
}

.gruene-liste li {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 30px; 
  line-height: 1.4em;
 }

.gruene-liste li::before, .gruene-liste li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -0.4em;
}

.gruene-liste li::before {
  content: counter(gruene-liste-number, decimal);
  counter-increment: gruene-liste-number;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.gruene-liste li::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<ol class="gruene-liste">
 <li>Das Ultrakurzzeitgedächtnis speichert Infos bis zu 10 Sekunden lang</li>
 <li>Das Kurzzeitgedächtnis speichert Infos bis zu 20 Minuten lang</li>
 <li>Das Langzeitgedächtnis, dessen Speicherdauer von der Stärke der Verankerung der Nervenzellen durch Synapsen abhängt.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another problem like you see in the picture. The padding-right does not work for wordwrap and if I change position to absolute the padding is deleted.

[image]

on this site: http://neuronade.com/kopie-sdfsdf-3

```css
ul.iconhaken li:before{
     content: '✔';
     color: green;
                          font-weight: bold;
     margin-left: -1em;
     margin-right: .100em;
                                        padding-right: 5%;
                                        position: relative;
    }
    ul.iconhaken {
     list-style-type: none;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="iconhaken">
 <li>Jede Uni hat Seelsorge-Stellen. Erkundige dich dort mal. Alternativ kannst du über folgende Website per Mail oder per Chat eine kostenlose Beratung erhalten.</li>
 <li>Jetzt bist du optimal auf deine Prüfungen vorbereitet. Also Ruhe bewahren und viel Erfolg!</li>
</ul>
```